# CE Certification process question

Tags: ce, compliance

Suppose I draft up the required technical documents and declaration of conformity.  Who do I submit the documents to and how long do they take to be approved ? Is there a strict format for the technical documents?

Comment: Some EU directives like Machinery require that you ship the declaration of conformity with every product (or hand out a URL link to it). I don't think this is true for all directives but I don't remember which ones that require it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are **self-certifying** then you hold onto those documents as part of your ISO 9000/9001 quality system. If someone challenges the validity of marking your product with the CE mark, you have 14 days to release the documents to demonstrate that you have used due diligence in self-certifying.

If you are wishing to CE mark a product that requires **approval by a notified body**, that notified body will inform you want to do.

Comment: I will be self-certifying.  Will anyone other than a government body challenge the validity of the product ? I Imagine the schematics will remain confidential unless someone challenges the CE mark.

Comment: Schematics aren’t necessarily part of the documentation. The product and configuration must be identified and the results of the prescribed tests and/or technical justification as to why the unit complies are what is required. If the unit was for hazardous areas, then the circuitry specific to compliance would be required.

Comment: I believe it is within 30 days (a month) at least in Europe.

Comment: @Kartman I was at a seminar with a RED Directive expert and said as much: "That's ridiculous, there's no way I'm going to hand out my design documents to some random person". And then he told me that we _had_ to, though in case we didn't want to hand out product/business sensitive info, it could be done with a test house signing a NDA and acting as middle man, then looking at the design to see if it compliant. Who is going to pay for the test house to do all that - nobody knows. Certainly not the EU bureaucrats that come up with all these dumb rules that can't be enforced in the real world.